# sed is not picking bash variable value

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file named webroot with below contents:

```
ROOT= .
#ROOT = Current Directory for Installers. Specify in double quotes.
```

I want to replace value foe first occurrence of ROOT with the path in double quotes, for which I created below script

```
#!/bin/bash

ppath="$(dirname $(pwd))"

sed -i '0,/^ROOT.*/s/^ROOT.*/ROOT = \"\${ppath}\"/' webroot

grep -m1 ROOT webroot
```

However, when I execute the script, I see below as output:

```
ROOT = "${ppath}"
```

Updated the script to below, however same result:

```
#!/bin/bash

ppath="$(dirname $(pwd))"

sed -i "0,/^ROOT.*/s/^ROOT.*/ROOT = \"\${ppath}\"/" webroot

grep -m1 ROOT webroot
```

Any suggestions, how this can be fixed?

Comment: Research quoting in shell. How it works? How does single quotes differ from double quotes? etc. As for pattern itself - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern

Comment: I've closed your previous question because it is a duplicate. Why are you opening another duplicate?

Comment: Because the link you provided in previous post suggested to put sed command in double quotes. And stackoverflow suggested to delete question and create a new one. I deleted old one and created new one after trying your input. But that did not work out.

Comment: @KamilCuk... i tried the link that you have provided, but using # and | in sed is also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used below:

```
sed -i "0,/^ROOT.*/s|^ROOT.*|ROOT = \"${ppath}"|" webroot
```